# Нужны символы для отображения шахматных фигур

Tags: c++, символы, ascii

Пишу программу моделирующую игру в шахматы, хочу использовать символы для отображения шахматных фигур, однако в таблице ASCII только 255 символов, в которых нет и намёка на шахматы.

---

Пробовал копировать символы и писать что-то типа

```
std::cout<<"♞";
```

Но компилятор выдаёт просто знак вопроса.

---

Может есть расширенная таблица символов? Или можно использовать вставленные символы чтобы они отображались нормально?

Comment: попробуйте изменить кодировку консоли на UTF-8 [How do I print UTF-8 from c++ console application on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35576741) и не забудьте программу тоже записывать с кодировкой UTF-8

Comment: @AlexGlebe не работает.

Comment: это больная тема, я через это прошел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так консоль не дружит с Юникодом и шрифтами, можно, как вариант, создать свой символ на базе существующего (можно нарисовать) и вставить в `wcout`(специализированный для "широких" символов).

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L""; // сюда вставлять символ
}
```

Чтобы создать свой символ:

1. Открыть редактор личных знаков(Eudcedit)
2. Нарисовать или использовать уже существующий символ. Откройте "Правка" -> "Копировать знак". Ищите лошадь под номером U+265e
3. Затем "Правка" -> "Сохранить знак"
4. Перезапускаем компютер
5. Копируем лошадку из программы "Таблица символов"
6. Вставляем в код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что это такое "редактор личных знаков"?

Comment: windows in-built  программа, которая позволяет создать свои символи, знаки

Comment: ну так бы и написали - Eudcedit. Не у всех же установлен русский язык в виндах.

Comment: Этот способ сохранит символ навсегда, или только в этой программе?

Comment: символ будет работать во всех ваших программах, но как я помню, только на комп'ютере, где этот символ создали

Comment: Есть уже готовый шрифт в виде шахматных фигур `CHEQ_TT` : https://www.fonts4free.net/chess-font.html

Comment: пробовал подключить этот шрифт - не получилось. Видно совсем гнусно с другими шрифтами в консоли